# How to fill Listbox with binary serialized data files - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

How can i grab all binary serialized data files in a folder, and put them in a Listbox? I have a list of .dat files in a folder. I would like to display them in the Listbox without the .dat file extension. Then have the user select one, deserialize it and load it. Thanks.

Comment: show us what you have done till now..

Comment: @Anand I have serialized some files to a folder. I have not done anything to put them into the Listbox as i don't know how to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Directory.GetFiles` method. It returns the list of files in the directory and also provides pattern search.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Once you have the list of files you can bind that list to your `Listbox.ItemsSource`